# How to serialize OpenLayers features?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I've got OpenLayer map. I'm drawing markers (named features) onto this map, but I don't know how to export/serialize these elements.

There isn't probably any function to export.

Here is my code

```
var map, vectors, controls;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "OSM",
                "http://a.tile2.opencyclemap.org/transport/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {layers: 'basic'});

        // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

        vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
            renderers: renderer
        });

        map.addLayers([wms, vectors]);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

        controls = {
            point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
            line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.Path),
            polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
            drag: new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors)
        };

        console.log(map.addControl(controls['point']));

        var control = controls['point'];
        control.activate();

        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(16.6833, 53.7167).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

        map.setCenter(position, 12);
        document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;
    }
```

Please for help me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found soulution. All elements are storage in vectors object

Comment: I don't know if this is what you found, but have a look at the write function of http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js. This will convert all your feature vectors to (Geo) JSON which is very useful for persistence.